# Django and channels, expose model data via websockets after save

Tags: python, django, django-models, websocket, django-channels

I am new to websocket and channel with django.
In my django project i would to expose saved data after a post_save event occur in a specific model via websocket.
I have django 3.2 and i install:

```
channels==3.0.4
channels-redis==3.3.1
```

then in my settings.py i add `channels` to my app list and set:

```
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'asgi_redis.RedisChannelLayer',
        'CONFIG': {
            'hosts': ["redis://:myredishost:6379/0"],
        },
        'ROUTING': 'backend.routing.channel_routing',
    }
}
```

chenge my application from WSGI to ASGI:

```
ASGI_APPLICATION = "backend.asgi.application"
```

then i try to create the `routing.py` file like this:

```
from channels.routing import route
from alarms.consumers import ws_connect, ws_disconnect


channel_routing = [
    route('websocket.connect', ws_connect),
    route('websocket.disconnect', ws_disconnect),
]
```

and connect and disconnect methods (insert every connected user ubto User group for now):

```
from channels import Group


def ws_connect(message):
    Group('users').add(message.reply_channel)


def ws_disconnect(message):
    Group('users').discard(message.reply_channel)
```

now i have an Results_Alarms model:

```
# Model of Alarms data
class Results_Alarm(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    var_id = models.ForeignKey('modbus.ModbusVariable', null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    calc_id = models.ForeignKey(CalcGroup, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    templ_id = models.ForeignKey(AlarmsTemplate, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    a_trigger = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name="Alarm trigger")
    dtopen = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name="Date of error")
    e_status = models.ForeignKey(AlarmStatus, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    dtclose = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name="Date of resolution", null=True, blank=True)
    u_involved = models.ForeignKey('accounts.CustomUser', related_name='oumanager', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    
    ...
```

I also create the `signals.py` file for manage the post_save event:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Results_Alarm)
def ws_alarms_data(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    #?? What here for send via websocket?
```

My problem now is: How can i trigger post_save event and send via websocket the last saved data (maybe in json format)? i have to create a router? but how?

Sorry but i am searching online without find an answer i can understand.

So many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you found the answer to your question. If I understood correctly, you want to send a message to the channel from the signals.
If this is the case you can use the `get_channel_layer` function in the [doc](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/channel_layers.html#using-outside-of-consumers)

```py
from channels.layers import get_channel_layer
channel_layer = get_channel_layer()

await channel_layer.group_send(
    "mychannel",
    {"type": "chat.message", "text": "42"},
)
```